# How can I install opus for Windows?

Tags: python, discord

Discord.py uses opus, but I didn't find how to install it.How can I do it?
This method doesn't work https://github.com/discordrb/discordrb/wiki/Installing-libopus
(or I am stupid)

Comment: _This method doesn't work_ Please be more specific.

Comment: It doesn't install opus.After using this method discord.opus_is_loaded() returns False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opus should be installed but not been loaded.
For this just put in your script:

> ```
> if not discord.opus.is_loaded():
>     discord.opus.load_opus(opuspath)
> ```

discord.opus.is_loaded() now should return True